# How use pointer of pointers in C functions?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, c99

I have an assignment in which I have to create a function to allocate a block with a starting index multiple of an int called "alignment" and a given size.

function prototype is

```
int block_alloc(void ** ptr_addr, size_t alignment, size_t size)
```

assuming that I call block alloc in that way:

```
int a=0;
ptr = &a;
void* ptr_2 = ptr;
ret = block_alloc ( &ptr_2 ,2* sizeof ( void*) , 2* sizeof ( int ) ) ;
```

I'm doing in block alloc

```
 ptr_addr = malloc ( sizeof (int) );
```

but when printing the pointer it return the &a location

I need to malloc in a given offset and make all work, any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change to `*ptr_addr = malloc ( sizeof (int) );`

Comment: What about address offset in malloc, it confuses me as I can use only c99 and stdlib functions

Comment: "of an int called "alignment" and `size_t alignment` confict. Is it `int` or `size_t`.  Please explain more what `alignment` is for.

Comment: " any hint on what I'm doing wrong?" [@John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69256464/2410359) has one of the issues identified (a key one).

Comment: Yeah, John answer is complete and solved all my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

As some programmer dude said, you need to change the expression to `*ptr_addr = malloc(sizeof(int));`, the explanation for it is as follows:

`**ptr_addr` is a pointer to the pointer that needs to be modified with the allocated space, so reassigning `ptr_addr = malloc(sizeof(int));` just modifies your local copy of the pointer to the pointer and creates a leak instead of modifying the pointer that is being pointed to, hence `*` dereferences the double pointer and allows you to modify the `ptr_2` variable.

Also your malloc call is wrong since you're completely disregarding the arguments and allocating the size for a single int only. The correct malloc call would be `malloc(size * alignment);` assuming `alignment` is meant to be the initial size of the array (Guessing from "initial index").

Answer (score 0):

Remember the basic pattern:

```
void update( T *ptr ) // for any type T
{
  *ptr = new_T_value; // updates the thing ptr points to
}

void foo( void )
{
  T var;
  update( &var ); // write a new value to var
}
```

Now let's replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`:

```
void update( P **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_Pstar_value; // update the thing ptr points to
}

void foo( void )
{
  P *var;
  update( &var ); // write a new value to var
}
```

In the second case, `var` has a pointer type `P *`, so the input parameter has type `P **`.  But we still want to update the thing `ptr` *points to*, so we still write `*ptr = ...`.

So in your case, you would write

```
*ptr_addr = malloc ( sizeof (int) );
```

in your `block_alloc` function, although I *think* they intend you to allocate memory as

```
*ptr_addr = malloc( size * alignment );
```

That allocates enough memory to hold `size` objects, each of which is `alignment` bytes wide.